# Using Renderer to do i18n?

Tags: internationalization, angular

I read recently [very interesting article](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2016/02/rendering-in-angular2.html) by @yearofmoo about Angular2 Renderer. It gave me an idea that it might be possible to do i18n with [Renderer](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Renderer-class.html). Basically use this function:

```
  createText(parentElement: any, value: string): any {
    // this is called for every text node in the template
  }
```

and simply transform `value` by mapping it to different language:

```
let es = { "Hello": "Hola" }

value = "Hello"
value = es[value]
```

I looked briefly at the [issues](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues?page=2&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+Renderer&utf8=%E2%9C%93) and [design docs](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1M9FmT05Q6qpsjgvH1XvCm840yn2eWEg0PMskSQz7k4E/edit), but before going down this rabbit hole I wanted to check if anyone has any experience with this.

Are there any issues that could prevent this from working? Some breaking changes on the way I'm not aware of? Opinions about this approach?

Comment: There shouldn't be issues as Renderer is what we should use since is webworkers safe. Breaking changes... can't say for sure, I don't think Renderer is going to change drastically over time, if it does at all. i18n will be supported oficially, that would be like a "stopper" to me, but that's my opinion and playing with angular2 is not wrong at all.

Comment: Agree with Günter and Thierry, thanks for sharing Sasxa!

Comment: np guys (; @EricMartinez, Good point for official support, hopefully they don't make it too complex/robust. I'll try to play with Renderer for transliteration for now...

Answer (score 1):

We use Renderer to set a translation that has been provided by a attribute.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, Renderer, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from './translate.service';

@Directive({ selector: '[translate]' })
export class TranslateDirective  implements OnInit{

    @Input() translate :string;

   constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer, private _translateService : TranslateService) {}

   ngOnInit(): void {
        this.renderer.setText(this.el.nativeElement,this._translateService.instant(this.translate));
   }
}
```

See [plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/uL7piBHRmobpRbQMMIvM/) for demo

Hopefully this is what you where looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but maybe others will stumble across it. :)

Also I realize Angular has built-in i18n mechanisms, but we didn't want to use them for a few reasons.  Primarily because we already have thousands of translated phrase mappings in another product, and we want to reuse all that.  So we convert the existing mappings into json, and then in our angular project:

1. Create a service (e.g. I18nService) with a function like:

```
export class I18nService {
    phraseMap: Map<string, string>; // fill this however you like

    translatePage(elements: QueryList<ElementRef>, renderer: Renderer2) {
        elements.forEach((el: ElementRef) => {
           let key:string = el.nativeElement.innerText;
           let phrase = this.phraseMap.get(key);
           if (phrase) {
              renderer.setProperty(el.nativeElement, 'innerText', phrase);
           }
        }
    }

// ...
```

this.phraseMap is a Map<string, string> with values like  key: "PH_HELLO"  value: "Bonjour"

In your component template, decorate your elements with a template variable (I used #i18n but can be anything), and replace the text with your phrase key, for example:

```
   <span #i18n>PH_HELLO</span>
   <div #i18n>PH_LOGOUT</div>
```

In your component class, collect all the appropriate elements using ViewChildren.  Inject your service and an Angular Renderer2, and implement AfterViewInit:

```
export class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {

   @ViewChildren('i18n', {read:ElementRef}) i18nElements: QueryList<ElementRef>;

   constructor(
      private i18nService: I18nService,
      private renderer: Renderer2 // from @angular/core
   ) {}

   ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.i18nService.translatePage(this.i18nElements, this.renderer);
   }
```